# Cannot see widgets in tab layout in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, widget

I am facing the problem of cannot see widgets in tab layouts. I have created textview and button in Overview Fragment but I cannot see them when run code. Is it right to initialize textviews and buttons in oncreateview() of fragment which we don't want to transfer to another tab. I have searched a lot about my problem but cannot get any hint. Code is given below:

```
package com.example.progluattempt;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class GlucosePlotterTips extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_glucose_plotter_tips);


        TabLayout Tablayout1 = findViewById(R.id.Tablayout1);
        TabItem OverviewTab = findViewById(R.id.Overviewtab);
        TabItem HistoryTab = findViewById(R.id.Historytab);
        TabItem TipsTab = findViewById(R.id.Tipstab);
        ViewPager Viewpager1 = findViewById(R.id.viewpagery1);

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Tablayout1.getTabCount());
        Viewpager1.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        Tablayout1.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Viewpager1.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}




//PgeAdapter
package com.example.progluattempt;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int numoftabs;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numoftabs){
    super(fm);
    this.numoftabs = numoftabs;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            return new OverviewFragment();
        case 1:
            return new HistoryFragment();
        case 2:
            return new TipsFragment();
            default:
                return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numoftabs;
}
}




 //Main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GlucosePlotterTips">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/Tablayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.004">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/Overviewtab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Overview" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/Historytab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/Tipstab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tips" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpagery1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



 //fragmentOverview

 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".OverviewFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="183dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewov2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="@string/overview1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewov3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonov2"
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="93dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/planner"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/Yellow" />
```

```
 //OverviewFragment

 package com.example.progluattempt;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView Results, Condition;
     Button Mybuttonov2;

public OverviewFragment() {

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

    Results = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewov2);
    Intent i =getActivity().getIntent();
    String LatestReading=i.getStringExtra("TimeofReading");
    Results.setText("Last Checked: " +LatestReading);
    //type
    Condition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewov3);
    String TypeofDiab = i.getStringExtra("Concentration");
    Condition.setText("" +TypeofDiab);

    //Button
    Mybuttonov2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonov2);

    //to display conditon of user
    if(Condition.getText() != null){
        String num;
        int numi=0;
        num = Condition.getText().toString();
        try{
        numi = Integer.parseInt(num);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){

        }


            if(numi <= 70){
                System.out.println("Hypoglycemia");}
                else if(numi >=70 & numi <= 140){
                   System.out.println("Fine");}
                   else if(numi>140 & numi <200){
                     System.out.println("Prediabetes");}
                        else {
                         System.out.println("Hyperglycemia");
            }
        }
    //to add click event for button
    Mybuttonov2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i3 = new Intent(getActivity(), SensorScreen.class );
            startActivity(i3);
        }
    });


    return view;
}
}
```

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XAGf.png)

[When run emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUQI2.png)

Comment: I think you missed attaching viewPager to Tablayout, try `Tablayout1.setupWithViewPager(Viewpager1)` after `Viewpager1.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);` in `onCreate()` method of GlucosePlotterTips class

Comment: It doesn't  work. I cannot find out my mistake since three days. Please review it again and suggest something.

Comment: Try setting proper constraint to your ViewPager in main.xml. Currently Its width and height is 0 and doesn't have proper constraint. please set topTotopOf, startToStartOf, endToEndOf, and bottomToBottomOf constraints, may this will help you.